# How to pass parameterized variable value in the Filename field of Flexible File Writter plugin of JMeter?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-maven-plugin

I am trying to pass a parameterized variable name which I have defined in "User Defined Variables" config element. When I try to access the variable value by ${variable_name} in the Filename field of Flexible File Writter plugin I am getting an exception.

One thing I would like to menion here, I am using the filepath based on the Maven architecture..

Below is the image of User Defined Variable config element in which I have created the variable named 'testDataFilesPath' having the path where I want to save the file.

[User Defined Variables Element where variable is created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DREL9.png)

Below is the image of exception which I am getting after executing the jmeter script:

[Exception after running the Jmeter script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NFmG.jpg)

Comment: Is your jmx file in the same folder path as mentioned in your User defined variable ?

Answer (score 1):

When you execute test via [JMeter Maven plugin](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin) the base folder looks like:

> \target\some [GUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier)\jmeter

therefore if your file lives under `src\test\resources\testData` you need to go one more level up, to wit:

```
../../../../src/test/resources/testData
```

Check out [How to Use the JMeter Maven Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-maven-plugin/) to learn more about the specifics of running JMeter tests via [Apache Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) build toolchain.

Comment: I tried by going one more level up (../../../../src/test/resources/testData) and executed the script, Still it shows the same error. below is the screen shot for the same: [After going one level up in file hierarchy][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3H11.png

Comment: then the file is not there

Comment: I even tried by manually creating the file in the path but it shows error. Correct me if I am wrong, after executing the script, file should be created automatically in the path which we have set in the variable. Right?